# Process cross domain xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, cross-domain, yql

In a web project using jsp, I have following requirement

Upload a file (say an image) to a different domain, which returns an xml that includes details of uploaded file (eg: path of uploaded image etc).

How do I capture this xml to save details in db?

I cannot do a normal html form submit, since I lose control after that. So I tried to implement this by setting form target to an iframe. But I cannot process contents of iframe?

Any suggestions how I can accomplish this?

Can I process this using yql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the server you are submitting the file to is not under your control (so you can't use CORS), you have proxy the request through your own server.

You can't use YQL as you can't make post requests with it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I get response xml as iframe content. Can I process this xml object using yql?

Comment: No, that is why I said "You can't use YQL". YQL gets data by making HTTP requests not by violating the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: ok. Can you tell me how do I use proxy? Do you have any example?

Comment: You pick a server side programming language. You find a library for it that lets you make HTTP requests. You make a request to the resource you want and then output it.

Comment: I tried using jsp, but I got **java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out**

Comment: Since I don't use Java, can't see your code and don't know how your environment is set up, I can't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using YQL. Not easy though, and you'll need to set up your own YQL table.

Each YQL table is a XML file describing how to operate on data. The YQL XML specification allows you to define an `<execute>` element that you can use to [write JavaScript code that does almost anything](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html).

Inside this `<execute>` block, you can use the [y.rest](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-javascript-objects.html#yql-execute-yrestobject) object to POST data somewhere else.

You'll probably have to encode the file using base64 to be able to actually POST data using the YQL syntax, something like `INSERT INTO mywebsite.files (name, data) VALUES ('foo.png', 'KBB987987JJBHBGV==')` (second param is a illustrative base64-encoded file).